# Close backend with AccessControl

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I can trying simple code.

I have an **AccessController** which having behaviors():

```
class AccessController extends BackendController
{
  public function behaviors()
  {
    return [
      'access' => [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
          [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
          ],
        ]
      ],
    ];
  }
  /*public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

    if( Yii::$app->getUser()->getIsGuest() )
    {
      return $this->redirect('/auth');
    }

    return true;

  }*/

  public function actions()
  {
    return [
      'WysiwygUpload' => [
        'class' => WysiwygUpload::className(),
      ]
    ];
  }

}
```

AS I understand, if I didn't declare **'only'** key, that is mean **to all** actions and controllers.

But nothing happen: no one error, nothing

Comment: What's mean nothing happen. explain your result and your expected goal..

Comment: Every Controllers (extends from AccessController) need to close from any Guests

Comment: Old solution is commented

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean. I don't understand...

Comment: What can be confusing is that I want to close the admin controllers?)

Comment: I never heard of closing a controller. What do you mean to close a controller. In a controller there are action, which are executed and  return a  result.

Comment: Close controller from guest it mean that's guests cannot to open it controllers because need to get Authorization before

Comment: Then you should set only the admin controller with this code  not the others

Comment: I tried to set 'only' section yet.  Nothing happen

Comment: I have post an answer ihope this is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  controller AccessController work only for yourApp/backend/access request  not for all controllerAction..

If you want deny the access to guest in AdminController you shuold apply the behavior of AdminController

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
       return [
           'access' => [
           'class' => AccessControl::className(),
           'rules' => [
              [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
             ],
          ]
        ],
      ];
    }
    ........
```

Then when a guest try accessing to  yourApp/backend/admin  this is not permitted

Comment: http://cs628729.vk.me/v628729930/2499e/bzH_m6PREIA.jpg  http://cs628729.vk.me/v628729930/249a5/1vYDQ_sN2E0.jpg  It nothing to happen (

Comment: Tried in in-cogito mode to open SiteController entire opening

Comment: Well, You can't controller the access to adminControlle in the way you proposed. You must define the access controller insde the controller you want allow or deny...

Comment: I found! I had public function beforeAction() in parent controller!